# debugging code that runs with debug flags and segfaults with opt flags

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a c++ code that segfaults with optimization flags, but not when I run it with debug flags. This precludes me from using a debugger. Is there any other way/ guidelines apart from a barrage of cout statements?

I am on a *nix platform and using intel-12.1 compilers and I am quite certain that it is a memory issue that I need to catch with valgrind. The only thing that puzzles me is why it does not show in the debug mode.

Comment: Any warnings in the code? What does the code do? Typically, this happens when you rely on undefined behaviour in some way or another (and sometimes caused by compiler bugs). You can usually build with debug information and with optimisation, so you get symbols to allow the debugger to tell you what function you are in, when the code is optimised.

Comment: what's your platform and compiler?

Comment: Even if you optimize, as long as you include debug symbols, you ought to be able to get a rough idea where the error is. Apart from loading the core dump, you can also run the program though memory debuggers like Valgrind or clang-asan and get clues where your bug is.

Comment: And write better unit tests maybe?

Comment: Also you can 1. Comment out parts of code, localising the problem. And 2. Check the part of code, which correspond to memory management for memory problems, for instance memory leaks. But I guess you asking something different? A tool?

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind is a useful tool for Unix-based systems for troubleshooting release-mode executables (gflags and WinDebug are useful for Windows.)

I also recommend not giving up on your debugger - you can run non-debug executables inside a debugger, and still get useful information about the segfault.  Often times you can also add in some level of debug information, even with optimizations turned on, to provide you more context.  You might also check for any debug-mode heap-checking facility that the intel compiler might provide, as these can go undetected in debug builds (due to different memory management).

Also note that there are usually multiple levels of optimization you can use for "release mode".  You might try backing down to a less aggressive optimization level, and see if the error still occurs.

You might also check the the Intel compiler web site to see if there have been any bugfixes/bug-reports regarding optimization for the compiler version you're using.

If none of these help, you can try using an alternate compiler (unless you're using something Intel-specific) to see if the problem is compiler-related or not.

Finally, as klm123 noted, commenting out blocks is a good way to localize the problem.